# GameCenter Player Id to Alias

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, game-center, leaderboard

In my app I am trying to convert GameCenter player ids to their aliases. Once I receive the ids I call the following method from a loop. The method is called with one id at a time and should return a single alias. I am just trying to return a single alias but can't get it to work. At first I put the return in the block however I found out that you can't return inside of it. Now I have it set up so it adds the object to an array and returns after the block however it is giving me the following error: [__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, retain) NSMutableArray * playerScores;
```

.

```
-(void)getScoresAndAliasForLeaderboard{
 [GKLeaderboard loadLeaderboardsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *leaderboards, NSError *nsError) {
        if( nsError != nil )
        {
            //error( nsError, "get leaderboard score" ) ;
            return ;
        }

        for( GKLeaderboard* board in leaderboards )
        {
            board.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime;
            board.playerScope = GKLeaderboardPlayerScopeGlobal;
            board.range = NSMakeRange(1, 100);

            [board loadScoresWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error) {
                 NSLog(@"board: %@",board.description);

                NSLog(@"error: %@",error);
                if (error == nil)
                {
                    for (GKScore *s in scores)
                    {

                        GCLeaderboardScore *playerScore = [[GCLeaderboardScore alloc] init];
                        playerScore.playerID = s.playerID;
                        playerScore.score = (int)s.value;
                        playerScore.rank = s.rank;
                        NSArray * player = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:s.playerID, nil];
                        [self loadPlayerData:player];
                        playerScore.alias = [_playerScores objectAtIndex:0];
                        NSLog(@"alias: %@, score: %d",playerScore.alias ,playerScore.score);
                        [_dataMutableArray addObject: playerScore];
                    }
                    [self.tableView reloadData];
                }
            }];


        }
                }] ;

}
```

.

```
-(NSString*) loadPlayerData: (NSArray *) identifiers
{
    if(!_playerScores){
    _playerScores = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
    [GKPlayer loadPlayersForIdentifiers:identifiers withCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *players, NSError *error)
     {

         if (error != nil)
         {
             // Handle the error.
         }
         if (players != nil)
         {
                 GKPlayer* player = [players objectAtIndex:0];
                 [_playerScores addObject:player.alias];
         }
     }];

    return [_playerScores objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`loadPlayersForIdentifiers: withCompletionHandler:` loads players asynchronously, hence the completion handler. At the time you as for `[_playerScores objectAtIndex:0]` the completion handler has not yet been called and `playerScores` is empty. This is the reason for the error you see.

For any solution, you have to embrace that asynchronous is asynchronous. For a very simplistic solution, you could have `loadPlayerData:` not return anything (`void`). `_playerScores` already looks like a member variable, and you could inspect it repeatedly at later times.

**EDIT**: The reference states explicitly that the completion handler is called on the main thread:

> Later, when the task is complete, Game Kit calls your completion handler. The completion handler is always called on the main thread.

That is nice, because then you can safely invoke `[self.tableView reloadData];` from within the completion handler of loading aliases. However, from your edits, two more issues become clear:

1. Within the `for`-loop over `scores` in the completion handler of `loadScoresWithCompletionHandler:` you repeatedly instantiate an array `player` for player IDs that you pass  to `loadPlayerData:`. It would be much nicer to fill this array first, and then invoke `loadPlayerData:` with all player IDs at once.
2. Even when you invoke `[self.tableView reloadData]`, `loadPlayerData:` will not have completed its job yet, because `loadPlayersForIdentifiers:` works asynchronously.

For a quick fix, I would may want to streamline the way you query player aliases and update your table view only after the player aliases have arrived from the Game Center server.

```
[board loadScoresWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error) {
    if (error)
    {
        return;
    }
    NSArray *player_ids = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (GKScore *s in scores)
    {
        [player addObject:s.playerID];
    }
    [self loadPlayerData:player];
}];
```

I left out your handling of the actual scores to make the point more clear. Now you only load player aliases once (having multiple leader boards is another issue that you may have to address separately).

```
-(void)loadPlayerData:(NSArray *)identifiers
{
    if (! _playerAliases) {
        _playerAliases = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    }
    [GKPlayer loadPlayersForIdentifiers:identifiers
        withCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *players, NSError *error)
    {
        if ((error) || (! players))
        {
            return;
        }
        for (GKPlayer p in players)
        {
            [_playerAliases setObject:player.alias forKey::player.id];
        }
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }];
}
```

Now you could use the `_playerAliases` dictionary to look up nicknames for player IDs. Since you invoke `loadPlayerData:` from within the completion handler of loading scores, all data *will* be ready after `loadPlayersForIdentifiers:` completes. Therefore, this a convenient time to trigger the update of your table view.

Comment: I am still a little confused on how you would restructure it. I have updated the question above to show how I am calling/implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

please user this demo for integration game center 
https://github.com/nihalahmed/GameCenterManager

Answer (score 0):

**Hi! it Works for me.**

> Here's my code :

```
GKLeaderboard *leaderboardRequest = [[GKLeaderboard alloc] init];

leaderboardRequest.identifier = kHighScoreLeaderboardCategory;



[leaderboardRequest loadScoresWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error)

 {

if (error) {




NSLog(@"%@", error);
        } 

else if (scores) 
{

        for (GKScore *s in scores)

        {
            NSLog(@"Local player name is : %@", s.player.alias);

             NSLog(@"Local player score's: %@", s.formattedValue);


        }

    }
}];
```